# How to integrate Robokassa payment gateway to Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway

I try to integrate Robokassa (Russian payment gateway) with my app. I've installed gem [rubykassa](https://github.com/ZeroOneStudio/rubykassa).

User will fill form on my site and after submit... I can't understand how to hash all this data with MD5 and send it to gateway.

It's helper in gem description, but how to attach it to submit event?

```
<%= pay_url "Pay with Robokassa", ivoice_id, total_sum %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `redirect_to` the user after form submit to specially constructed url, if I remember right, robokassa does support get-parameters.

Other way is just to present the user with another form filled with hidden fields and submit button saying "proceed to payment"